# multiplication of Nx1 column vector with Nx3 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a column vector Nx1 and a matrix Nx3 and I want to multiply the first element of the Nx1 with all the elements of the first row of the Nx3 matrix and the second element with all the elements of the second row of the Nx3 and so on.
Using for loop it is possible to do it.
Is there any other way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the faster solution is the following:

```
C = A.*[B,B,B];
```

where `A` is the Nx3 matrix and `B` the Nx1 matrix

Comment: It is so simple idea and I had exactly the same one before I see the answer.

Comment: It's not just simpler, it also just takes 0.06% of the evaluation time compared to bsxfun.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose `A` is `n`-by-3 and `x` is `n`-by-1 vector.
It's so much fun with [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun):

```
>> myLongExpectedResult = bsxfun( @times, A, x );
```